# ipcop + active directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, internal-dns, dhcp-server, ipcop

im planning to install IPCop linux in my company.
My problem is that the current router/dhcp/server is also running active directory.

What configuration should I use to keep the old active directory service in the old computer and new services (dns, dhcp, etc) in other server?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to move these services?  Moving DNS will break your active directory environment.

Comment: ahh, well, im going to keep the dns in the active directory machine until i get rid of AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straight forward to disable these services on the windows box.  But be warned, moving DNS is likely a bad idea.  AD is VERY sensitive.  Make sure when you move it that the client and server stay pointed to the same DNS and monitor the event logs to ensure AD stays healthy.